# Jar File only working on my computer

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I have code to run a simple runtime test on how long it takes to run a simple file, once it completes that I output the results to a file in the public users folder. It works on my computer but not on anyone other. This is my code

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import javax.swing.*;
    public class Speed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final long length=100000000;
        List merh = new List();
        File filename = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\filename.txt ");
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             merh.add( "Hereherehehrehrehrherh");
        }
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) 
);

        Writer writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(

                  new FileOutputStream(filename), "utf-8"));
            writer.write("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report
        } finally {
           try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {/*ignore*/}
        }


     }


}
```

Comment: Does it give you any error messages? Does that other computer have a C:\\Users\\Public\\filename.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an absolute pathname, which you should try to avoid. The reason it's failing is likely because the other computer you're using it on doesn't contain the directory `C:\Users\Public\`. Instead, you should use `System.getProperty("user.home")`. This line:

```
File filename = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\filename.txt ");
```

Would therefore become:

```
File filename = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\filename.txt");
```

[System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: Where does the filename.txt end up then?

Comment: On Windows, it will end up in `C:\Users\CurrentlyLoggedInAccount`. If you want to find your home directory, you can type `cd %userprofile%` in the command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

This Code is working perfectly fine. I tested this in my machine and output is

Total execution time: 6728

What error are you getting on other machines